# MySQL query with if condition where clause

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I have table ORDERS with id, appId, status, orderId.

> status can - OK, ONHOLD, DONE, REJECT etc
>
> ```
> For this use case i want to filter with 
>     status OK and ONHOLD
>     and order
>       if status is "OK" - I want to get allow all orderIds
>       if status is "ONHOLD" - only get ids with whiteList orders.
> Here the statusList has 2 Strings and whiteListOrders dynamically generated list
> ```

```
 public List<Long> getIds(
   @Bind("appId") String appId,
   @BindIn("statusList") List<String> statusList,
   @BindIn("whiteListOrders") List<String> whiteListOrders);
```

How to achieve this in mysql query

Comment: what column determines if the row is whitelisted?

Comment: orderId column : if the orderId exists in the whitelistorders list

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the generic query -

```
SELECT <req cols> 
FROM   mytable1 
WHERE  status='OK' 
UNION 
SELECT <req cols> 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  status='ONHOLD' 
AND    id IN 
       ( 
              SELECT orderids 
              FROM   <whitelistorders>)
```

If you can provide the table and column details, you can do it with join as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could union the queries. This will give you the data you want.

```
(SELECT ids FROM ORDERS WHERE status='OK' AND ids IN (@whiteListIds))
UNION  
(SELECT ids FROM ORDERS WHERE status='ONHOLD' AND ids IN (@whiteListIds))
```

As mentioned, this would be possible without the `UNION`:

```
#set @whitelist = your whitelist IDS; /* Not sure how you have this setup */
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  user 
WHERE 
  status='OK' 
  OR (
    status='ONHOLD' 
    AND id IN (@whitelist)
  )
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score -1):

Neither of the supplied answers is optimal, as they both use a UNION. There is no reason whatsoever to do this, you can easily add whatever multiple clauses you need by combining clauses inside your WHERE clause using a combination of AND, OR and parenthesis.

I'd also consider using `and exists(subquery)` rather than using `in (subquery)`

Comment: Could you please share and example query for this one.

Comment: Following my answer @miroslav_glamuzina has added the correct version. Not sure who or why this was down-voted.